# What is the difference between I haven't eaten since morning and I haven't been eating since morning?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between I haven't eaten since morning and I haven't been eating since morning ?Feel free to just provide example sentences.

Comment: "I haven't been eating since morning" sounds unidiomatic (too short a timespan); it could perhaps be used to counter "You've been stuffing yourself all afternoon and evening".

Comment: *What is the difference between* both versions are used in a series of context - sometimes both will be correct, sometimes only one. Without context, your question is difficult to answer.

Comment: The progressive form would be used to indicate a deliberate abstention from eating.

Comment: @Robusto I suppose so but it's not that clear. I'd say either "I've been not eating since morning" or, preferably, "I have been refraining from eating since morning".